# Multi container access and get data in same usb port

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, modbus, modbus-tk

Hi Im using Docker container for getting data from device via USB RTU 485 using modbus RTU.

At this moment, I can use single Docker container for getting from that. But when Im using multi container it have problem about getting that data because data not going right container.

Ex: Container 1 send request data to device id 1,2,3,4. At the same time container 2 send request to device id 5,6,7,8. But when data go back it go wrong, container 1 get data from device id 5,6,7,8 and container 2 get 1,2,3,4.

Is there anyway to fix that problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with using Docker containers with USB devices. You can try using a different USB controller, or you can use a single container and mount the USB device into that container.

Comment: Are you have link about notice this issue ?